# Rails: Set a private value so it only calls the database once

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, accessor

I have the following method to check if a user has admin access.

```
  def has_admin_access?(user)
    user.present? && gym_users.where(:role_id => [3, 4]).where(['user_id = ? AND date_ended IS NULL', user.id]).any?
  end
```

The problem comes when I want to call this multiple times on a page.  How can I do this so that I set a private value and only make the database call the first time?

Comment: In production, Rails will only perform the database query once. You don't need to do anything special to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the result in a hash, and if you look up the same user again return the result from the hash. Like this:

```
def has_admin_access?(user)
  @admin_hash ||= {}
  if (!@admin_hash.include?(user))
    @admin_hash[user] = user.present? && gym_users.where(:role_id => [3, 4]).where(['user_id = ? AND date_ended IS NULL', user.id]).any?
  end
  @admin_hash[user]
end
```

Comment: You have @admin on there as well as @admin_hash, what's the value of @admin?

Comment: Sorry, a typo from coding in the browser. It should be @admin_hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable
memoize :has_admin_access?
```

[more information](http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/09/20/a-guide-to-memoization/)